# why do you use the :: operator to declare an iterator for a map, but not to declare the map itself?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I declare the map:"mymap" I do not need the ::
But when I declare an iterator "mymapiterator" then I do need the :: operator, why is that?

```
map <int, string> mymap;
map < int, string >::iterator mymapiterator;
```

Comment: If you're not using `std::map<>` to declare your map, you're employing a bad practice. What's important is to look up what exactly `::` is. That's the better question. It's called the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 4):

The `iterator` is a nested class within `std::map`.  You refer to nested classes using the `::` operator, e.g. `std::map<int,int>::iterator`.  Note that I used the `::` operator to refer to `map` within the namespace `std` as well.

For example...

```
struct A {
    struct B { };
};

A my_a;
A::B my_b;
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out there is a class `std::iterator` so here the qualification ensures the map iterator is used not the generic helper base class?

Comment: @Persixty [Deprecated since C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) – not sure if it is worth the effort.

Comment: @Aconcagua But still there. I was just offering colour to why even having namespaces is useful. I've never actually used or relied on `std::iterator` it's fairly redundant.

Comment: @Aconcagua so how do you do it instead? Thanks. You mean with auto?

Comment: @tucooperacion There's no *'instead'*. The answer tells you exactly how to do; we've been discussing if to mention `std::iterator`, an entirely different type. `auto` is fine in those cases where you initialise the variable immediately (like `auto i = someMap.begin(); /* do something with i */`). If you cannot for whatever reason you declare just as described – *or* sometimes you might fall back to `decltype`, too: `decltype(someMap.begin())` – note that the content within `decltype` is not executed, so you might use it on some kind of invalid map (maybe a null pointer of that type?), too.